# Native Instruments Audio Kontrol 1 - crackling sound

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa

I am very new user to the Linux world. I istalled newest Ubuntu on my old ASUS A7CC laptop. I would like to use also my older external sound interface Native Instruments Audio Kontrol 1. I am able to choose *Analog output (Audio Kontrol 1)* When I am at Sound settings menu. But the sound coming out is very glitchy / cracky, I dont know how to describe it... Maybe the best example is situation when you have very limited buffer size on your ASIO sound interface and you have slow PC too and you keep getting buffer underruns in some DAW application.

Any idea how to fix this issue?